# Is it possible to have multiple require.js projects included in one html file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I would like to do something like this:

```
<script data-main="/js/D4/build/mainD4" src="/js/D4/build/require.js"></script>
<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

I could just build the first file, and the include the build js file in /js/main, but it would be much faster to be able to do development on both projects side by side without having to build all of the time.  Right now when I try this, mainD4 builds and then nothing happens with the js/main file.

Answer (score 6):

Just found the answer here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/requirejs/YWFdgYSU2f4

```
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/main"></script>
<script>
require(['scripts/another/main']);
</script>
```

or

```
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/main"></script>
<script>
(function(){
  var req = require.config({baseUrl:'scripts/another'});
  req(['main']);
}());
</script>
```